# Identity Server 4 in ASP.NET Core Angular - how to share css?

Tags: css, angular, asp.net-core, razor, identityserver4

I have scaffolded Identity Server pages. I need to style them same way as the rest of the app. However it seems to have its own "root". And I cant find the way to share the theme css.

The theme css comes from `devextreme` and as long as I can see it is deployed in `dist/styles.460fbddcdafd4abc24c1.css` file.

The whole app sees it and I dont need to use `link` as it is builds automatically into `dist\index.html - <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.460fbddcdafd4abc24c1.css"></head>`

IS4 root seems to point at `~/Identity` path. So it cant find the theme css classes.

The only solution so far is - to copy the theme css file to `wwwroot` and add to `_Layout.cshtml`:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/../dx.dark.css">`

Is there another, *correct* way to do it?

Comment: I have the same issue.  Any custom css file I want to reference in the `_Layout.cshtml` file gives a 404 at runtime while all the `Identity` files are ok.

Comment: there is zero support for identity server. do the same as i did - copy stuff into wwwroot.. or else your gonna wait till end of time